# What is the most efficient way of storing and querying for hastags in a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am in the process of structuring my MYSQL table, I am building a platform with Laravel where a user is able to upload an image that includes a description. This description will include hashtags.

Now I am wondering what the most efficient approach might be to storing the description and searching it.

Initially I thought of storing the description as as whole within a single text column and doing a simple search after indexing the column. This would allow the user to search by hashtags and general words.

I then wondered if it would be more efficient to extract the hashtag and store it in its own table against the photos ID. This idea would work well if it was only able to search by tags but you can also search by regular words as well.

Can anyone confirm what the best approach might be or even suggest another.

Thanks

Comment: It's better you have it. Even Stackoverflow has a table for tags. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: I'm afraid relational database management systems like MySQL are not designed for text search. You may need a full text search engine like Lucene or Solr or ElasticSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you *store* the data depends on how you want to *access* the data.

If you only want to ever *see* the descriptions and hash tags, then you can put them into a single unindexed field and fetch them when for each image.

From what you speify, you seem to want a `descriptions` column that is searchable as text.  This may be sufficient for your purposes.

However, if you want to be able to ask questions specifically about hash tags such as:

- What hash tags are in the database and how many?
- What hash tags are on a specific image or set of images?
- What hash tags do two images have in common?
- What hash tags "contain" other hash tags (i.e. #cat and #catamaran)?

Then you will want a separate table of hash tags.  My recommendation would be to combine the two.  Something like:

```
create table images (
    imageId int auto_increment primary key,
    description text,
    createdAt datetime,
    createdBy varchar(255),
    fulltext (description)
);

create table imageHashtags as (
    imageHashtagId auto_increment primary key,
    imageId int not null,
    hashtag varchar(255),
    constraint fk_imagehashtags_imageid foreign key (imageid) references images(imageid),
    index (hashtag)
);
```

You might conceivably want a reference table for the hashtags themselves, so they are not duplicated in the table.  There is not enough information to know if that is a good approach.